# What is meant by ionization states?

Tags: astrophysics, spectroscopy

I am going through the theory of [Saha equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saha_ionization_equation) but I am not able to understand the concept of ionisation state? What are ionization states actually?

Comment: I guess this question is more appropriate at physics.SE, but briefly: It's the degree to which an atom — or an ensemble of atoms — is ionized. That is, is it missing one, two, three, etc. electrons. But beware: Whereas chemists, and normal physicists I think, use the notation (with iron as an example) Fe, Fe$^{+1}$, Fe$^{+2}$, Fe$^{+3}$, etc. for neutral, singly-ionized, and doubly-ionized, triply-ionized iron, astronomers use Fe I, Fe II, Fe III, Fe IV, etc. That is, [astronomers' Roman number] = [chemists Arabic number] + 1.

Comment: The comment by Pela is the correct answer. Astronomers needed a way to designate the neutral or un-ionized state.

Comment: @pela In fact, this goes to Chemist SE (ionizing atoms).